# Plotting the Lorentz Constant in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, physics

I'm having trouble producing a graph of the Lorentz constant, defined by

`\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$`

as a function of `$v$`. (Here, `$c$ = $3 * 10^8$`).

I tried many examples, but I usually get "dimensions too large." Any help is appreciated. I want the plot to show the vertical asymptote as `v^2` approaches `c^2`.

Comment: Please don't use dollar signs, i.e. `$$...$$` to show math expressions. Instead, use ```. We are not in Math.SE `:P`.

Comment: Just a physics note: Indeed, as @marmot noticed, it doens't really make sense to call it the Lorentz 'contant' - usually it is called the Lorentz factor, or the gamma factor (as it is most often written as a lowercase gamma).

Answer (score 12):

Well, if this was a constant, it would not really be worth plotting, would it? I use natural units in which $\hbar=c=1$. To show that units do not matter, I am labeling the x-axis `v/c`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Lorentz(\x,\c)=1/sqrt(1-(\x/\c)*(\x/\c));}]
\begin{axis}[ymax=pi,ylabel={$\gamma$},xlabel={$v/c$}]
 \addplot[blue,domain=0:1,samples=100] {Lorentz(x,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]